# Answer is different then OP asking for

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

While reviewing the low quality post queue, I got [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10747092) for review. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10747097) is the another answer from the post, which I got in the review queue as well.

It was posted 5 hours ago and 1 hour back OP has mentioned that his question is not about merging multiple branch in git. So it seems, user miss-understood the post and answered it. It also got some upvotes from other users. Even both the answer on the OP post are about merging multiple branches.

Post: [How to merge one current branch into multiple following branches at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556494/how-to-merge-current-branch-into-multiple-branches-at-once)

Review Queue Post-1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34556540/2254048

Review Queue Post-2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34556577/2254048

What action should I take in this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

More often than is desireable, answers that a user believes to be altogether wrong end up flagged as low quality and in the LQP queue. This is not how the flags should be used, but alas it happens. Sometimes you will find a high quality correct answer with a comment that implies the answer is wrong, and flagged as low quality by another answerer in the hope that it will be deleted, so their (perhaps later) answer can rule supreme.

In your case, the answer is clearly of high quality. It may be completely wrong (I have no idea - although the comments do suggest the answerer got the wrong end of the stick), but it's presented well and has a good explaination. In this case you should review the post as *Looks OK*, and then if you wish go to the answer and downvote/comment accordingly.

See [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer)

You're not expected to be an expert on every subject of every post in the LQP queue, and certainly not expected to be a judge of the correctness of an answer. As I mentioned above, I have no idea if the answer is right or wrong - the commenter may be wrong and the answerer correct - but there's no reason to delete the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're unsure, so the *best* option in this scenario (as far as the review is concerned) would be to skip it.

As for the actual answer, if it seems that it's incorrect, you should take action on it independent of the review.